# How to diagnose the 'Oops! Entered absent arg' GHC error?

Tags: haskell, exception, runtime-error

When running my GHC program, I see the following runtime error:

```
my-program: Oops!  Entered absent arg moduleLen Int
```

Unfortunately, the error message is not that helpful. I wonder, what does this error usually mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Care to post your program code?

Comment: Which version of GHC are you using?

Comment: That should not happen. You either have found a GHC bug or there is some problem with the build process. It's hard to tell without knowing more.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! Unfortunately, I can't provide a code snippet, it's a part of a huge codebase, and I wasn't able to reproduce this with a minimal example. I'm using GHC-8.10.1 and I was hoping to get some ideas about possible places to look at...

Comment: Well at the very least, ghc 8.10.2 fixed some bugs, so maybe yours was one of them. It's worth a shot.